# Data Augmentation Examples

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, error, mixture-distribution, measurement, data-augmentation

I am looking for applied references to data augmentation (preferably with some written code).  Either online references are books would be great.

I found this book online:

[http://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Missing-Data-Problems-Biostatistics/dp/142007749X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1291905761&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142007749X)

But with no reviews I am hesitant on purchasing it.

Thanks!

Edit:  I have two variables X and Y.  Let's say X follows a mixture of normals and there is a logistic relationship between X and Y.  There is measurement error when observing X.  We observe 100 X Y pairs and need to estimate the function between the two.

In a book on measurement error (John P. Buonaccorsi) the author recommends data augmentation (I believe the introduced variables are the true X means) for estimation.  However no details are given.  I am looking for simple examples (R code but doesn't really matter) to get started.

Comment: [The Art of Data Augmentation](http://j.mp/hiZ5ED), by van Dyk and Meng may be a good start. I also quickly found some R examples on Bayesian statistics on [Peter M. Lee](http://j.mp/fslE35) and [Brian Neelon](http://j.mp/h1yJyQ)'s websites. But I guess you can find other good tutorials with Google, or a more experienced user will have some good recommendations to offer.

Comment: Great thanks.  Anyone know of a good book/textbook reference?

Comment: Maybe you could add some info about its intended use and the target language .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Art of Data Augmentation](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1391021), by van Dyk and Meng may be a good start. I also quickly found some R examples on Bayesian statistics on [Peter M. Lee](http://j.mp/fslE35) and [Brian Neelon](http://j.mp/h1yJyQ)'s websites. But I guess you can find other good tutorials with Google, or a more experienced user will have some good recommendations to offer.

*Originally an upvoted comment by chl*